# Where should I save simple configuration settings?

Tags: clojure, config, compojure, luminus

In my clojure Luminus/Compojure app I have this in `routes.clj`:

```
   (def page-size 12)
   (def images-path "/public/images/.....")
```

I need to move them to a config of some sort. Where is the best place? I'd like something simple and not to use any additional library on top on the ones that I'm already using which come with Luminus.

Answer (score 4):

Luminus uses it's [`config`](https://github.com/yogthos/config) library for configuration. [You can put your configuration variables into appropriate `config.edn` files (per environment).](http://www.luminusweb.net/docs#the_env_directory) Config values are available as a map stored in `config.core/env`. You can see an example in your `<app>.core` namespace:

```
(defn http-port [port]
  ;;default production port is set in
  ;;env/prod/resources/config.edn
  (parse-port (or port (env :port))))
```

Comment: can I have a setting shared between all environments? for example, I want `page-size` always to be equal 12 in all of them, but I don't want to repeat myself.

Comment: I would write my own code which would read a file with common config (e.g. `common-config.edn`) and merge it with `config.core/env` one and use it instead.

Comment: I was equally surprised to find out that cprop doesn't read any common config file by default. Using Luminus, add this to your <app>config.clj: (defstate env :start (load-config
                       :merge
                       [(source/from-resource "common-config.edn")

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself this question:

> Would I ever want multiple deployments of my application where this setting differs?

If the answer to that question is "yes" then the configuration should be dictated by the environment running you application either by an `edn` file, [Environ](https://github.com/weavejester/environ) or other means.

If not... then you are talking about something I would categorize as an application constant, which helps avoiding [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). In some situations it can improve readability by placing these in specific namespaces like so.

Constants namespace:

```
(ns my.app.constants)

(def page-size 12)
(def images-path "/public/images/.....")
```

Application:

```
(ns my.app.core
  (:require [my.app.constants :as const)

;; now access the application constant like this
;; const/page-size

(defn image-url [image-name]
  (str const/images-path "/" image-name))
```